# Encrypted hexadecimal string for an email address with possible set of characters [A-Z, a-z, 0-9, @,.,_]

Tags: encryption, md5, decode, encode

The encrypted string:

(1f49487495a3ab3bd18e770507559b76)9a78211436f6d425ec38f5c4e02270801f3524f8(e5b4c6df38f1eb0475d366ea903e9fe4)3a52ce780950d4d969792a2559cd519d7ee8c727(af10ef20dd9060bbeead0afbc55381a66af442ef)

Encryption algorithm is unknown.

Comment: Do you have a decryption key? This could be everything!

Comment: No i dont have decryption key. I have given this string and told me to decrypt this

Comment: This question cannot be answered. Because, first, we don't know what kind of encryption methodology is used. Second, we don't know the key to decrypt it. And finally, if a hash function is used, decryption is impossible.

Comment: Is there any alternative to decode this

Comment: If we knew, that the encrypted message was alphanumeric english text, than we could try to guess. Especially if it was a really simple form of encryption (like a character table, or similar).

Comment: So last thing i want to know that how could i supposed to guess this string to a simplified text

Comment: What is the context here? Is this a quiz or interview question?  Are those `()` accurate?

Comment: Yes this is an interview question. And the brackets are accurate

Comment: Are you sure you're not breaking a copyright or NDA by posting it here?

Comment: It is just an interview question

Comment: try this for each string you will get your answer it is sha1 encrypted key http://www.hashkiller.co.uk/sha1-decrypter.aspx
ans is techcareer@retale.in

Comment: @Devnegikec there is no such thing as SHA1 encryption. SHA1 is a hash function, not a cipher. Also, they aren't all SHA1. A few are MD5.

Comment: The Email address is : techcareer@retale.in

Answer (score 2):

This message could be literaly **any** encrypted text.

You could image an ecryption method, that encrypts `hello` or `asdfg` to the string you posted. As long as we don't know, which encryption method was used, there is an *infinite* amount of possible solutions to your problem.

The solution could even be this:

```
)fe244fa66a18355cbfa0daeebb0609dd02fe01fa(727c8ee7d915dc9552a297969d4d059087ec25a3)4ef9e309ae663d5740be1f83fd6c4b5e(8f4253f10807220e4c5f83ce524d6f63411287a9)67b955705077e81db3ba3a59478494f1(
```

if an encryption method was used, that just reverses the text.

---

What would help to solve your problem:

- What is the context of that string?

  - Is it an exercise in a book?
  - Is it a test, that a friend of yours gave you?
  - Have you stolen the text from a company's computer?
  - Have you encrypted the text yourself and don't know the key anymore?
- What kind of encryption method has been used?

  - AES
  - blowfish
  - etc.
- What kind of solution do you expect?

  - Is it an ecrypted binary JPG-image?
  - Is it a password?
  - Is it english/german/frensh/spanish text?
- Give us more information about the author

  - Firstname, Lastname
  - Company name
  - Family member names
  - pet names
  - postal code, address
  - friends, school names, hobbies, etc.

---

Assuming that it is a test, that a friend gave you. And assuming, that the solution should be some kind of english text, I made these analysis:

encrypted text:

```
(1f49487495a3ab3bd18e770507559b76)9a78211436f6d425ec38f5c4e02270801f3524f8(e5b4c6df38f1eb0475d366ea903e9fe4)3a52ce780950d4d969792a2559cd519d7ee8c727(af10ef20dd9060bbeead0afbc55381a66af442ef)
```

formatted:

```
(1f49487495a3ab3bd18e770507559b76)
9a78211436f6d425ec38f5c4e02270801f3524f8
(e5b4c6df38f1eb0475d366ea903e9fe4)
3a52ce780950d4d969792a2559cd519d7ee8c727
(af10ef20dd9060bbeead0afbc55381a66af442ef)
```

- It contains of `5` groups of different sizes
- Every second group is enclosed by brackets

getting rid of brackets:

```
1f49487495a3ab3bd18e770507559b76
9a78211436f6d425ec38f5c4e02270801f3524f8
e5b4c6df38f1eb0475d366ea903e9fe4
3a52ce780950d4d969792a2559cd519d7ee8c727
af10ef20dd9060bbeead0afbc55381a66af442ef
```

- The groups each consist out of an even number of characters

These characters are contained:

```
0: 14 times
1: 9 times
2: 11 times
3: 10 times
4: 13 times
5: 16 times
6: 10 times
7: 13 times
8: 10 times
9: 13 times
a: 11 times
b: 8 times
c: 7 times
d: 11 times
e: 15 times
f: 13 times
```

- all characters are lower case
- all characters can be used as "hex"-numbers

Analysing pairs of two characters:

```
04: 1 times
05: 1 times
07: 1 times
09: 1 times
0a: 1 times
10: 1 times
14: 1 times
1f: 2 times
20: 1 times
21: 1 times
22: 1 times
24: 1 times
25: 2 times
27: 1 times
2a: 1 times
35: 1 times
36: 1 times
38: 2 times
3a: 1 times
3b: 1 times
3e: 1 times
42: 1 times
48: 1 times
49: 1 times
50: 1 times
51: 1 times
52: 1 times
53: 1 times
55: 1 times
59: 1 times
60: 1 times
66: 1 times
69: 1 times
6a: 1 times
70: 1 times
74: 1 times
75: 1 times
76: 1 times
77: 1 times
78: 2 times
79: 1 times
7e: 1 times
80: 1 times
81: 1 times
8e: 1 times
90: 2 times
95: 1 times
9a: 1 times
9b: 1 times
9d: 1 times
9f: 1 times
a3: 1 times
a6: 1 times
ab: 1 times
ad: 1 times
af: 1 times
b4: 1 times
bb: 1 times
c4: 1 times
c5: 1 times
c6: 1 times
c7: 1 times
cd: 1 times
ce: 1 times
d1: 1 times
d3: 1 times
d4: 2 times
d9: 1 times
dd: 1 times
df: 1 times
e0: 1 times
e4: 1 times
e5: 1 times
e8: 1 times
ea: 1 times
eb: 1 times
ec: 1 times
ee: 1 times
ef: 2 times
f1: 1 times
f4: 1 times
f5: 1 times
f6: 1 times
f8: 1 times
fb: 1 times
```

Grouped by frequency:

```
once: 04, 05, 07, 09, 0a, 10, 14, 20, 21, 22, 24, 27, 2a, 35, 36, 3a, 3b, 3e, 42, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55, 59, 60, 66, 69, 6a, 70, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 7e, 80, 81, 8e, 95, 9a, 9b, 9d, 9f, a3, a6, ab, ad, af, b4, bb, c4, c5, c6, c7, cd, ce, d1, d3, d9, dd, df, e0, e4, e5, e8, ea, eb, ec, ee, f1, f4, f5, f6, f8, fb
twice: 1f, 25, 38, 78, 90, d4, ef
```

- There are `82` different character couples. This is more than the **26** characters of the english alphabet, even more than *52* if you take Upper- and lowercase in account. I assume, that the encryption method was [not a simple substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher#Simple_substitution)

---

Assuming that the number of characters did not change by encrpytion, I expect an answer in this format (`+` stands for character, that was found twice, `-` stands for character, that was found once):

```
+--------------- -+----++-+------+--- ----+-------+--- ---+--+----+-------- --+--+-------------+
```

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get.

Comment: What will happen when we reverse the string

Comment: I made this post *community wiki*, you all are welcome to add any ideas or conclusions.

Comment: It is a question that my frnd have been asked.

Comment: It is in english and behind this code there is an email address to find

Comment: @slartidan Great writeup. Too bad it will be deleted along with the question in some time.

Comment: @ArtjomB., it won't be deleted automatically since it has upvotes. SO only automatically deletes closed questions if nothing has been upvoted.

Comment: @mikeazo Yes, at the time it didn't have any upvotes and I generally assume that people don't upvote answers on closed questions. I guess that assumption is not always correct.